# Can a Linear-Log model be used instead of Robust Standard Errors?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, data-transformation, robust-standard-error

If your regression model has heteroskedastic residuals, one should calculate White Standard Errors that correct for the mentioned heteroskedasticity.  If the residuals are also autocorrelated one should use Newey-West Standard Errors.

However, I was thinking of another alternative.  How about turning your linear regression into a Linear-Log one.  You would transform the X variables into LN(X) variables.  The advantage of that is that the Standard Error of those LN(X) variables' regression coefficients would be elastic so to speak.  That's because logs have a multiplicative instead of additive nature.  So, when your regression coefficient is associated with a higher value of X the Standard Error even though the same in a log form would be much larger when antilogged or delogged (converted back from log form to nominal by using the EXP() formula).  As a result, when the estimate and resulting Standard Errors are anti logged... the resulting Confidence Interval automatically widens.  With smaller values of X, as specified the antilogged Confidence Interval would automatically narrow.

I would think such Linear-Log model would be more effective at fully resolving heteroskedasticity than using White Standard Error that still comes up with one single fixed Confidence Interval (resulting in two parallel lines to the regressed line).  The Linear-Log model instead would come up with an ever widening interval as the value of X increase.

Given that the Linear-Log model appears superior to White Standard Error to resolve heteroskedasticity.  I wonder if it also would work as well or better than Newey-West Standard Errors to resolve autocorrelation of residuals.  I don't see why not.  The main issue with autocorrelation is that such autocorrelated residuals could persistently trend outside of the Confidence Intervals limits that are parallel to the regression line.  As demonstrated above, the Linear-Log model overcomes this issue.

You would only use the Linear-Log model as a test of statistical significance of the variables.  You would still use the regular linear model to estimate your dependent variable.

What do you think?  What am I missing?

Comment: You use "should" several times in your opening paragraph, as if those calculations were the only way to deal with the issues. Is there a justification for this use of 'should' rather than 'can'?

Comment: "Can" is fine.  You are welcome to edit the text.  Otherwise, as stated I trust the language is clear enough to warrant precise responses.

Comment: I have no wish to edit your text at present; rather I simply sought to understand why it is written the way it is (if it really *is* a should, there's something I don't know but ought to - and there is no lack of such cases).

Comment: By "$X$ variables" do you mean the *dependent* or the *independent* ones?

Comment: I thought this was an international convention that "Y" is a dependent variable and "X" is an independent variable.  And, I have never come across the reverse.